# Reducing a boolean/logical matrix to a (non square) permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a Boolean/logical $n\times m$  matrix with $n>m$, is there an efficient way to determine if there is a way to 'reduce' this to a matrix with exactly one 1 in every row (there does not need to be a 1 in every column, but there cannot be more than 1). Here, reducing means choosing certain 1s and changing them to 0s. For example,

$$A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1& 0 \\
  0  & 0  & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$ can be reduced to
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$
but 
$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$ cannot be reduced.

Comment: "Exactly one $1$ in every row..." is inconsistent with your first example. Please elaborate on the rules used.

Comment: My bad - there doesn't need to be a 1 in every column, just in every row.

Comment: Then you'll want $n<m$ or $A\in \{0,1\}^{m\times n}$, since the first sentence right now demands more rows than columns and your example is the other way around.

Comment: @mbender1 You can't edit freely or comment because the account you're using is different from the one you used to ask the question. Please follow the instructions at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Answer (score 0):

After a few rephrases, you have a necessary condition that the row sum of $A$ must never be $0$, since that means that there are no $1$s in a row at all. Looking at the columns, you'll need to partition the columns in a way that each partition forms a submatrix $A_{j}\in \{0,1\}^{n_j\times n_j}$ such that the column sums of all $A_j$ are also nonzero and that no rows or columns of $A$ are reused in multiple $A_j$. This means that after a permutation of rows and columns, call them $P$ and $Q$,
$$PAQ = \pmatrix{A_1& \ast & \ast \\ \ast & A_2 & \ast \\ \ast & \ast & \ddots}$$